# Custom Payment Method issue in Magento 2.4.5

Tags: checkout, forms, payment, magento2.4.5

Create a Custom Payment Method in Magento 2 but face this issue on the checkout page.

> {   "message": "Please enter a valid credit card expiration date.",
> "trace": "#0
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Payment.php(202):
> Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc->validate()\n#1
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/PaymentMethodManagement.php(79):
> Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment->importData(Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject))\n#2
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php(181):
> Magento\Quote\Model\PaymentMethodManagement->set(311,
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment))\n#3
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
> Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformation(311,
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), NULL)\n#4
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
> Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...',
> Array)\n#5
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
> Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(311,
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), NULL)\n#6
> /home/public_html/magento245/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement/Interceptor.php(32):
> Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...',
> Array, Array)\n#7 [internal function]:
> Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->savePaymentInformation(311,
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), NULL)\n#8
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#9
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(195):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy))\n#10
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#11
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
> Array)\n#12
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#13
> /home/public_html/magento245/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(23):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
> Array, Array)\n#14
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#15
> /home/public_html/magento245/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#16
> /home/public_html/magento245/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#17
> /home/public_html/magento245/index.php(48):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#18
> {main}" }

**Please check the screen shot**

[issue image](https://prnt.sc/62NKcDhjmlij)

Comment: I tihink cc_exp_year and cc_exp_month  does pass from your credit card form  magento payment api

Comment: Kindly provide the payload for the request as it would assist in identifying any missing elements or information in the request.